# Domain Driven Design in Functional Programming?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, domain-driven-design

Is there an equivalent of DDD in FP? It seems to me that DDD is only valid in OOP paradigm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends how seriously you preach the DDD gospel:

- If you buy into all the details of Erik Evans's book, especially the stuff in Part II that is heavily object-oriented, than no sane person would try to duplicate that in a functional language.
- If your interest is primarily in Part I of the book, that everyone on the project should have in common a language in the domain, then the leaders in the functional-programming movement have been in the area of *embedded domain-specific languages*.  These are common currency now, but a [paper by Erik Meijer and Daan Leijen at DSL'99](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/emeijer/Papers/HaskellDB.pdf) did a great deal to make these techniques popular.  Constructing an embedded DSL is now a very popular technique in functional programming, and if you search for [embedded domain specific Haskell](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=embedded+domain+specific+Haskell) you will find many examples.

So my answer is: *the important, foundational ideas of Domain-Driven Design can be applied in a functional setting*, but many of the object-oriented details are irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

Domain Specific Languages. See for example [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130305529).

Answer (score -1):

DDD eXchange 2012: Greg Young on Functional Programming with DDD

http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/design-architecture/ddd-functional-programming